# Nikon F mount Adaptable Lenses/Mounts with infinity focus

Tags: nikon, lens-mount, lens-adapter, adapter

I know that Nikon F mount is platform that not much lenses can be adapted to. Is there any type of lenses that can be adapted to Nikon F mount(modern DSLR or old film) without any lens modifications, using just adapter and have fully functional lens with infinity focus.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)

Comment: not really but thanks

Comment: Then please edit your question to include why it doesn't answer ir - as it's a fairly comprehensive list of which lenses can be adapted to which bodies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As xiota mentioned, the answer is no, if you're talking 35mm SLRs lenses. The only vintage 35mm SLR mount that's deeper than Nikon F is Leica R, and only by 0.5mm, so there's no simple ring adapter that's going to work and maintain infinity focus.

You could use a simple ring adapter for **medium format** SLR lenses, say, [Hasselblad V-mount](https://fotodioxpro.com/collections/nikon-f-adapters/products/hbv-nikf) or [Bronica-S](https://fotodioxpro.com/collections/nikon-f-adapters/products/brns-nikf-pro), but those will be substantially more expensive, bigger, and heavier than 35mm lenses, and they'll be coming in longer focal lengths that won't do  wide angle, particularly if you're shooting with a DX crop body.

But if you're willing to expand your definition of "adapter" and wobble a little on "without lens modifications", [Leitax](http://leitax.com/) makes lens mount replacement kits (no machine shop required) to adapt certain Leica R, Contax/Yashica, and Olympus OM lenses to Nikon F.  Keep in mind, not all lenses in those mounts can be adapted, and lenses in those three mounts tend to go for premiums among vintage lens users ('cause Leica and Zeiss are *always* pricey, and Zuiko OM lenses are compact and very high quality).

See also: [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any type of lenses that can be adapted to Nikon F mount(modern DSLR or old film) without any lens modifications, using just adapter and have fully functional lens with infinity focus.

**There are no other DSLR mounts whose lenses will retain infinity focus without modification when adapted to Nikon F.** There are some universal mounts that can be used (T-mount, adaptall, etc). Several medium format mounts are also long enough.

You can search your favorite auction site to see if anyone has made any adapters for the mounts you're interested in using.

Note: While Leica R is 0.5mm longer than Nikon F, that isn't enough space to fit an adapter.

See Wikipedia: [Flange Focal Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flange_focal_distance).